# How to select alt+anykey or shift+anykey in react-hotkeys?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-events, hotkeys

I searched but did not found anything and tried the below code but it did not worked.

`keyMap = { ALT_ANY: 'alt+*' };`

My question is how can I map any key with `alt`?
I mean if user press any character key or any key with `alt` .

For example:- `alt+a`, `alt+b`, `alt+c`, `alt+d`..... all together in one event.

[react-hotkeys](https://github.com/greena13/react-hotkeys) in case you need library link.

Answer (score 0):

I have not found solution with react-hotkeys, but i have another, may be it'll work for you:

```
import React, {Component} from "react";

export default class extends Component {

    reportKeyEvent = ({altKey, key}) => (altKey && key !== 'Alt') ? console.log(`Alt+${key}`) : null

    render = () => <input type="text" onKeyDown={(e) => this.reportKeyEvent(e)} /> 

}
```

Comment: No, I don't want it on specified input focus, I want it on any input of page, document or doesn't matter where is focus, that's why I'm using library.

Comment: I propose you my [decision](https://codepen.io/KoldunMax/pen/bzvrRR?editors=1010) without any libs, hope you'll catch my idea